# DLL_THREAD_ATTACH not called when a COM DLL is invoked via IIS app pool w3wp.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting *some* DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notifications in my COM DLL, but *none* from the app pool worker threads, from which my COM DLL is actually invoked.

Subsequently, calls to the DLL initiated from IIS arrive on threads for which DLL_THREAD_ATTACH was never called.

Only the first thread of the app pool is notified when the DLL is attached to dllhost.exe (via DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH).

Is this a defect or a feature, and is there any workaround?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant and you point being? ps. I'm not calling DisableThreadLibraryCalls. And besides, DLL_THREAD_ATTACH *is* being called for other threads, just not for worker threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` is often misunderstood. You don't give enough information, but it is likely that your problem is due to this :

From the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx), emphasis mine :

> DLL_THREAD_ATTACH | **The current process is creating a new thread**.

On the same page :

> There are cases in which the entry-point function is called for a terminating thread even if the entry-point function was never called with DLL_THREAD_ATTACH for the thread:
>
> - The thread was the initial thread in the process, so the system called the entry-point function with the DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH value.
> - **The thread was already running when a call to the LoadLibrary function was made, so the system never called the entry-point function for it**.

To work around this, you can either manually enumerate every thread of a process when `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH`. You can also do a first time init when your DLL functions are invoked on a new thread. Obviously, you can also create the threads AFTER the DLL is loaded, if it is possible.

Comment: Yes, that was it! The worker threads are already running when my DLL is loaded. Never would have thought :)